# Is save for multiple bash scripts to append to the same log file?

Tags: bash, logging

I would like to save multiple bash scripts to the same log file to be able to precisely monitor which event happened before another event.

Just to create some tests I have executed three bash scripts at nearly the same time.

File A.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
watch -n 1 'echo AAA $(date '+%Y%m%d%H%M%S%N') >> mylog.log'
```

File B.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
watch -n 1 'echo BBB $(date '+%Y%m%d%H%M%S%N') >> mylog.log'
```

File C.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
watch -n 1 'echo CCC $(date '+%Y%m%d%H%M%S%N') >> mylog.log'
```

And in log file I see:

```
AAA 20220211083057445268276
BBB 20220211083058398227435
CCC 20220211083058417044373
AAA 20220211083058453956479
BBB 20220211083059419856946
CCC 20220211083059436848192
```

All this looks fine.

What will happen if two bash scripts write to log file at exactly the same time? Is there some file locking implemented, so B.sh has to wait until A.sh writes to log file, or will B.sh just overwrite the A.sh record?

Comment: It's possible for the log entries to interleave. With append mode, the overwriting should be impossible.

Comment: You could consider using the `logger` command that logs to the various system logs - see `man logger`.

Answer (score 1):

As "rici" stated, if you use the 'append' mode when opening then concurrent access, it shouldn't be an issue, however, the results may not be in the order you would expect.  Adding a time-stamp to your log entries would probably help to de-tangle them.

Concurrent access will also mean that a process will have to wait at some time.  I wouldn't expect long waits, but that also depends on how frequently a process will be appending. Waits might cause further issues for you down the line, especially if the number of concurrent access attempts grows (large number of processes or endless loop).

I'm not well versed, but you might want to look at the syslog system or similar; it could be a alternate option that possibly remove the some of the idiosyncrasies of concurrent file handling/writing (while bringing others ;-) ).